# Pythagorean Triplets with sum less than $1500000$

Tags: linear-algebra, pythagorean-triples

Consider any Pythagorean Triplet $(\sqrt{a*b}, \frac {a-b} {2}, \frac {a+b}{2})$. For generality, consider $a>b>0$.
Now we are given than sum of sides is less than $L=1500000$
$$\implies \sqrt{a*b}+a\le L$$
$$\implies \sqrt{a*b} \le L-a$$
Since $L.H.S$ and $R.H.S$ are positive, squaring them gives:
$$\implies a*b \le a^2 -2La +L^2$$
$$\implies a^2 -(2L+b)a +L^2 \ge 0$$
Using basics of Quadratic Equations, the above equation has minimum value of $(\frac{4L^2-(2L+b)^2}{4})$ at $a = \frac{2L+b}{2}$.
$$\therefore \frac{4L^2-(2L+b)^2}{4} \ge 0$$
$$\implies {4L^2-(2L+b)^2} \ge 0$$
$$\implies (2L+b)^2 \le (2L)^2$$
$$\implies -4L \le b \le 0$$
This is surely not a correct result. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: What exactly are you asked to do? You've stated the hypotheses for a question, but not the actual question. (Your last line says "correct result", correct result to what?)

Comment: I meant just imposing a bound on sum of sides of triangle lead me to a result $b \le 0$ where as my assumption was $b > 0$. I am basically imposing an equality check on sum of sides of right triangle $\le L$, and then trying to find the corresponding bounds on values of $a,b$.

Comment: Are you trying to solve Project Euler problem 75?

Answer (score 1):

I can’t see how that formula will give a Pythagorean Triplet, so perhaps you could start with $$2kab,k(a^2-b^2),k(a^2+b^2)$$
where $gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a,b$ are of opposite parity.
Then
$$L=k(2a^2+2ab)$$

Minimum $L=12$ is given by $(k,a,b)=(1,2,1)$

Maximum $L= 1499996$ is given by $(k,a,b)=(193,58,9),(29,134,59)$

**Addition 23 Sept 2016.**

You asked where you went wrong, and it’s with the formula for a Pythagorean Triplet.
Substitute some small values for $a,b$ to see that, unless $ab$ is square, you contravene the very definition of a Pythagorean Triplet; a right-angled triangle with integer sides.
IMHO, it’s wasted effort to look further errors.

Although there are three parameters, for the maximum it’s sufficient to calculate just for $k=1$, then recalculate $k$ as $1500000/L$ where $/$ is used here as integer division.

Comment: How that formula forms a Pythagorean Triplet? Well,
 $(\sqrt{a*b})^2 + (\frac {a-b} {2})^2 = ( \frac {a+b}{2})^2$.

Comment: Your analysis sounds good. +1

Answer (score 0):

You have an inequality, you are looking for positive solutions. You found that if you add one condition (that for a fixed $b$, $a$ is chosen so that a certain function is minimized), you get an absurd result. All this means is that **your added condition is absurd**. There are of course plenty of non-absurd Pythagorean triples, just that they don't satisfy $a = (2L + b)/2$.

To make things more clear:

if you suppose $a = (2L + b)/2 = L + b/2$, then assuming $b > 0$ you already have 
$$ \sqrt{ab} + \frac{a-b}{2} + \frac{a+b}{2} > a > L $$
which means that your postulate $a = (2L + b)/2$ **already violates your length constraint** that you started with. So by the principle of "garbage in, garbage out", of course you get a seemingly ridiculous bound.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(A+B+C)=P=(m^2-n^2 )+2mn+(m^2+n^2 )=2m^2+2mn$

We can find triples, if they exist, for a given perimeter by factoring for $\space n\space$ and testing a defined range of $\space m$-values to see which, if any, yield integers.

\begin{equation*}
n=\frac{P-2m^2}{2m}\space
\text{for}  \space \biggl\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{4P+1}+1}{4}\biggr\rfloor\le m \le \biggl\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{2P+1}-1}{2}\biggr\rfloor
\end{equation*}

The lower limit ensures that  $m>k$ and is found by solving for $\space m\space$ when $\space n=m-1.\quad$
The upper limit insures that $k\ge1$ and is found by solving for $\space m\space$ when $\space n=1.\quad$

Given $P=149990,$ the greatest [primitive] perimeter $\space P<150000, $ we have
$\quad m_{min}=192,\space m_{max}=273\quad \text { and we find }\\ f(265,18)=(69901,9540,70549)$

I don't know how it would apply to your formula unless you multiply all the terms by the least common multiple and then factor. Remember, Euclid's formula generates only primitives, primitive doubles, and perfect square multiples of primitives. If we find a greater perimeter, we will have to factor to identify a non-square multiples of a primitive and then show that primitive times a factor of the perimeter.

None of the divisors of $149999, 149998$, or $149997$ yields an $m$ for which $n$ is an integer but $149996=(2^2 * 7 * 11 * 487)=(154*974)$

We find
$\space\biggl\lfloor
\dfrac{\sqrt{4*154+1}+1}{4}\biggl\rfloor
=5\le m\le
 \biggl\lfloor
\dfrac{\sqrt{2*154+1}-1}{2}
\biggr\rfloor
=8$

and testing, we find
$$f(7,4)=(33,56,65)\\\longrightarrow (32142,54544,63310)
\quad GCD(974),\space P=149996$$

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar I do not know what I was thinking when I posted this answer in 2019. I have made corrections to the limits and added explanations about how they are derived. I hope this helps.

Comment: I triple checked the equation, and still can't match up the lower limit you arrived to from the equation `4m^2 - 2m - P = 0` when `n=m-1`. The positive solution for the equation is `(1 + sqrt(1 + 4P)) / 4`, not `(-3 + sqrt(1 + 4P)) / 4`. Also, I'm not seeing any relation established with `k`, so, the statements "The lower limit ensures that m > k" and "The upper limit insures that k >= 1" seem hand wavy to me. Lastly, you refer to some function `f` which I don't see defined anywhere. Perhaps you assume some prior knowledge on the matter, but I'm not just used to so many gaps.

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar You are correct. My error was in solving for 
$\space n \space$ instead of $\space m.\quad$ Also, my reference to 
$\space k \space$ was an oversight, copying from another paper I wrote where I have two forms of Euclid's equation that are
$\quad F(m,k)\quad\text{and}\quad F(n,k)\quad$
 where the only difference is that $\space F(m,k)=F(2n-1+k,k).\quad$ I developed the $\space F(n,k)\space$ formula independently in $2009$ without knowing that Euclid's formula even existed. $\quad$ MY formula generates all primitives and some odd square multiples.

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar  
If you are curious, I have used my formula many times on MSE and you should be able to find it easily but email me (see my profile) if you would like more details.
\begin{align*}
&A=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k\\
&B=&&2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\
&C=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k+2k^2
 \end{align*}